# How would I apply a transition to a navigation element?

Tags: html, css

I'm basically trying to add an animation to my navigation so when a user hovers over the links the text color fades in blue, and then fades back out to black after. I've read up on the transition property and watched a few tutorials on Youtube but I can't get it to work when I apply it to my own navigation bar.

Below is a link to my Codepen, if anybody could shed some light on the problem I'd be really appreciative..

Thanks

HTML:

```
<!-- header starts here -->
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

http://codepen.io/Clarkpen/pen/razMWB

Comment: `transition` should not contain the target value, but it should contain the animation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myMrRq

I included a transition on the anchor:

```
nav ul li a {
  transition:all 400ms ease-in;
}
```

Note it is good practice to add the vendor prefixes:

```
nav ul li a {
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1400ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 400s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

**EDIT**

I have edited your codepen here to only add the transition to the navigation links:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNZGpL

Answer (score 0):

```
 nav ul{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
 nav ul li{float:left;list-style:none;}
 nav ul li a{text-decoration:none; padding:15px; color:#666; text-transform:uppercase;transition:ease-in 0.5s;-webkit-transition:ease-in 0.5s;-ms-transition:ease-in 0.5s;-moz-transition:ease-in 0.5s;}
 nav ul li a:hover{background:#F00; color:#FFF;}
```

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:;">About US</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Products</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Feedback</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/dreamsweb/pen/LEjRyb)

Comment: You may want to consider re-formatting your CSS to make it more easily readable and to add an explanation behind this approach. This will make your answer easier to understand.